# Can I change the default Explorer folder in Windows XP (with a twist!)?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer

I know how to pass command line arguments to explorer.exe in the properties of a shortcut, but what I'm trying to do is a little bit different.

I want to change the folder that Explorer opens up to **when you right-click the start menu and then choose explore** in Windows XP.

I'm talking about this menu:

[image: Start context menu]

Comment: If you don't want to Explore the Start menu folder, why are you right-clicking on the Start button?

Comment: I have a user that's accustomed to opening explorer this way and was wondering if they could have it default to a different folder. It's fine if it's not possible, but that doesn't invalidate the question.

Comment: I suppose its possible...It would be fair easier to show the user the correct way or use a desktop icon.

Comment: It's a valid enough question that MS changed the behavior in later versions of Windows!  I'm not sure what Vista does (no installations handy to test), but as @techie007 posts, Windows 7 defaults to a more useful (but probably still not user-customizable) location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other's have suggested in their comments, when you do that you are specifically requesting to Explore the Start Menu.

From my understanding changing it is not going to be easy, if even possible, as it will probably require hacking/patching the Explorer.exe.

In Windows 7 they changed the Start button's right-lick to give you a straight "Open Windows Explorer", which opens Explorer to your "Libraries" folder instead of the Start Menu's folder, so maybe it's time for an upgrade? ;)